# How to install tailwind-rn?

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I have been trying to use tailwind for my react native project but for some reason it won't work.

I've done "npm install tailwind-rn" and then "npx setup-tailwind-rn" but nothing changes in my app.

This is the code I have

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import {SafeAreaView, View, Text} from 'react-native';
import {TailwindProvider, useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';
import utilities from './tailwind.json';

const App = () => {
    const tailwind = useTailwind();

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={tailwind('h-full')}>
            <View style={tailwind('pt-12 items-center')}>
                <View style={tailwind('bg-blue-200 px-3 py-1 rounded-full')}>
                    <Text style={tailwind('text-blue-800 font-semibold')}>
                        Hello Tailwind
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const Root = () => (
    <TailwindProvider utilities={utilities}>
        <App />
    </TailwindProvider>
);

export default Root;
```

but all it does is get the "Hello Tailwind" sentence to the top left of the screen. Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

**STEP1:** What you need to do is first go and follow each and every instruction and you will be able to solve your issue.[Tailwind CSS RN Docs](https://tailwindcss-react-native.vercel.app/quick-start)

**STEP2:** Check your package.json it should look like this-

```
   {
  "name": "expo-tailwind-example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "build:tailwind": "tailwindcss --input input.css --output tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer && tailwind-rn",
    "dev:tailwind": "concurrently \"tailwindcss --input input.css --output tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer --watch\" \"tailwind-rn --watch\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~44.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.14.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "tailwind-rn": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "concurrently": "^7.0.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.12",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Initially your utilities will be empty, Do not panic but as you use classes it will be filled with styles.

**CHILL**

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't finish the remaining configuration

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).